# PyCharm should warn me if I use % to format strings

Tags: python, pycharm, code-inspection

PyCharm has a lot of inspection rules to warn me if my programming style is either unmodern or  problamatic.

Because [string formatting with `%` is not as clean as `.format()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format), I want to force myself to use the newer approach. I would like that PyCharm supports me and warns me if I use `%` to format strings instead of `.format()`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `%` won't be replaced. It's still in Python 3, and it isn't deprecated. `.format` is simply considered somewhat cleaner.

Comment: I corrected my question to respect this important detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Searching](http://forum.jetbrains.com/search?q=custom%20inspection&f=PyCharm) PyCharm's forum for *custom inspection* reveals [topic](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-1049) titled *Is there a way to create custom inspections in pycharm*, with the following response from Dmitry Jemerov:

> Yes. The inspections have to be written in Java, though. You can find
>   plugin development information at
>   http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment
>
> If you're still interested :) I could provide more details.